# Unable to interact with Autodesk View after MarkupsCore Extension custom code

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am using Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore Extension for marking up rectangle in 3d viewer while orientation of the view is TOP.

Then I am saving the coordinates and deleting all the markups.

But after I leave *EditMode* and remove all the markup I neither can move the view nor can rotate it.

I have tried this:

```
 if (this.state.markupOn) { // this is the condition of leaving the markup
       markupExtension.leaveEditMode();

      svgData = markupExtension.generateData();
       markupExtension.unloadMarkupsAllLayers();
      markupExtension.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
      markupExtension.leaveEditMode();
      window.Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.Utils.showLmvToolsAndPanels(
        this.viewer
      );
      this.setState({ markupOn: !this.state.markupOn });
      return;
    }
```

After trying all this I am unable to interact with view. Please help me with this.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. I've taken some time to edit your question to properly format code and improve the title. We encourage users to take care of proper code formatting for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the markups extension is explained in this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension.

If you followed this article and you're still having issues, please send us a more complete code sample to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` so that we can explore it further.

Comment: <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.min.js"></script>
doesn't working now, can you please advise correct url?

Comment: While the extension itself remains relatively unchanged, the viewer itself has evolved significantly since the blog post was published. Please refer to the official [getting started](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics) section to see how the viewer should be initialized.